# Panda3d Modules Autocomplete in Vscode 1.68

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm sorry for my English skills.

I have a problem with importing Panda3d modules in Vscode 1.68. When I try to import modules like **core**, **ai** or **ect**, vscode's autocomplete doesn't recognize them.
[autocomplete not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGdo2.png)

In my photo you will realize that the classes and function does not appear in vscode's autocomplete of import statements, and panda3d.ai in this statement is white; that means that the import process is not being done correctly.

I installed panda3d by `python -m pip install panda3d`. My python version is **3.10.5** and the panda3d version is **1.10.11**.

I want to be able to import these modules correctly and **see content of these modules in vscode's autocomplete**.

Please help me solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the image you've shown. Please add your question so that we can reproduce your problem better. For example, your error interface, your operation, the effect you want to achieve, etc.

Comment: Vscode does not show functions and classes in panda3d modules . If you notice to my image Vscode's autocomplete does not show these functions and classes.

Comment: How did you install the library? Maybe in a virtualenv or similar? Your screenshot shows you're using a "3.10.5 64-bit" interpreter, which doesn't sound like a virtualenv.

Comment: I have tested with venv and install panda3d with pip but i got result same as global python.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the python extensions or maybe for some reason the extension is not working.

In order to use Panda3D in Visual Studio Code, you should get the Python extension.

- Click on Extensions and then type in ‘python’ in the search box/.
- Then install the first extension in the results list by clicking on the Install button.

You could reinstall `panda3d` if this persists.

```
pip install panda3d
```

Comment: I have done this method but I have got same result as before .

Answer (score 0):

Please use `ctrl+shift+P` to open the command palette, then select `python: select interpreter` to select the correct interpreter.

Your `panda3d` package may be installed in a different environment. Installation information can be checked with `pip show panda3d`.

**Answer update:**

> This problem is caused by the lack of `.subs` files in `panda3d` package, not vscode. Related problem has been raised in [GitHub](https://github.com/panda3d/panda3d/issues/1327). Please wait for the update of package.